# Unable to commit using bazaar tool to my unfuddle svn

Tags: 13.04, svn, bazaar

Till now I was using "Rabbit VCS", but after changing my laptop somehow unable to install it properly. So, I have become a new user to "bazaar" which can be installed directly from "Ubuntu Software Center".

Checked out the code from Unfuddle.com which worked perfectly fine.
Getting below error while performing my first commit using bazaar's GUI tool.

> python:
>   /build/buildd/subversion-1.7.5/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1253:
>   svn_relpath_basename: Assertion `relpath_is_canonical(relpath)'
>   failed.

There is a bug raised on this at [Ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/1055427). However couldn't find any fix for that.

Comment: Since, I am not able to get RabbitVCS on my Ubuntu 13.04 (somehow!) and Bazaar is not working, for time being I have installed another GUI tool named as [SVN Work bench](http://stackoverflow.com/a/86954/514235). This is helpful for me to checkout-checkin my code in Unfuddle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps hve bzr-svn installed? It sounds like you might be opening a svn repository through bzr from within RabbitVCS.